# SparkLauncher Run spark-submit with yarn-client with user as hive

Tags: java, hadoop-yarn, apache-nifi, spark-launcher

Trying to run spark job with `masterURL=yarn-client`. Using SparkLauncher 2.10. The java code is wrapped in nifi processor. Nifi is currently running as root. When I do yarn application -list, I see the spark job started with `USER = root`. I want to run it with `USER = hive`. 
Following is my SparkLauncher code.

```
Process spark = new SparkLauncher()
    .setSparkHome(cp.fetchProperty(GlobalConstant.spark_submit_work_dir).toString())
    .setAppResource(cp.fetchProperty(GlobalConstant.spark_app_resource))
    .setMainClass(cp.fetchProperty(GlobalConstant.spark_main_class))
    .addAppArgs(ps.getName())
    //   .setConf(SparkLauncher.DRIVER_EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS,"-Duser.name=hive")
    .setConf(SparkLauncher.DRIVER_EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS, "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///opt/eim/log4j_submitgnrfromhdfs.properties")
    .setVerbose(true)
    .launch();
```

Do I need to pass user as driver extra options? Environment is non-kerberos.
Read somewhere that I need to pass user name as driver extra java option. Cannot find that post now!!

Comment: `export HADOOP_USER_NAME=hive`

Comment: Did you try spark.yarn.principal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

export HADOOP_USER_NAME=hive worked. SparkLauncher has overload to accept Map of environment variables. As for spark.yarn.principle, the environment is non-kerberos. As per my reading yarn.principle works only with kerboros. Did the following

```
Process spark = new SparkLauncher(getEnvironmentVar(ps.getRunAs()))
                        .setSparkHome(cp.fetchProperty(GlobalConstant.spark_submit_work_dir).toString())
                        .setAppResource(cp.fetchProperty(GlobalConstant.spark_app_resource))
                        .setMainClass(cp.fetchProperty(GlobalConstant.spark_main_class))
                        .addAppArgs(ps.getName())
                        //   .setConf(SparkLauncher.DRIVER_EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS,"-Duser.name=hive")
                        .setConf(SparkLauncher.DRIVER_EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS, "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///opt/eim/log4j_submitgnrfromhdfs.properties")
                        .setVerbose(true)
                        .launch();
```

Instead of `new SparkLancher()` used `SparkLauncher(java.util.Map<String,String> env).`Added or replaced`HADOOP_USER_NAME=hive.`
Checked `yarn application -list`launches as intended with`USER=hive.`

Comment: For the record, that env variable is used by the Hadoop client libs, not by Spark itself.